# How to convert decimal answers into trig simplifications (symbols)?

Tags: trigonometry, calculator

When I use the calculator to get the result of [this integral](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RDHod.png) I get a decimal number. However, in my calculus book, as shown on the picture, the answer was represented using some trig symbols!

Is there is a way to show the same result, but not in decimal only? I want to use symbols like `pi` or `sin` to represent my answer. Just like my book. could it be done using the calculator?

Comment: Do you by chance mean $\tan^{-1}(\tan (9))$?

Comment: $$\tan^{-1}(\tan y)=y$$ and $$\tan(\tan^{-1}x)=x$$  Not sure about the $3\pi$ part

Comment: @labbhattacharjee That moves the angle into the proper interval; the arctan function always returns a number between $-\pi/2$ and $\pi/2$.

Comment: @CarlHeckman,  You mean $3\pi$ moves the angle into the proper interval? But its already in $\left[-\dfrac\pi2,\dfrac\pi2\right]$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee 9 isn't in that interval.

Comment: @CarlHeckman, Oh ok ok. You meant $$\tan^{-1}(\tan y)=y$$  Thanks

Comment: @CarlHeckman yeah I meant that (the inverse of tan (tan 9) ). So, the inverse tan is the outside function, and tan is the one inside. Sorry for the confusion. I am not familiar with this website yet.

Answer (score 1):

Your calculator won't be able to do this in general. However, if you have an expression of the form $\tan^{-1}(\tan y)$, this can be simplified using facts about the tangent function.

First of all, let $t=\tan y$. There are infinitely many values of $x$ such that $\tan x = t$ (because the tangent function is periodic). Since the period of $\tan x$ is $\pi$, that means if you have one angle $x$ whose tangent is $t$, then $\tan(x+k\pi)=t$ as well; in fact, these are all such values.

Now, the arctangent (inverse tangent) function $\tan^{-1}(t)$ chooses a number $x$ such that $\tan x=t$ and $\displaystyle-{\pi\over2}\le x \le {\pi\over2}$; this value exists and is unique. So you need to find the value of $k$ that puts $x+k\pi$ into this interval.

For example, let $t=\tan9$. Then $9$ is one of the reals $x$ such that $\tan x=\tan 9$. The rest are $9+k\pi$. Now you need to choose $k$ so that $\displaystyle-{\pi\over2}\le 9+k\pi$ and $\displaystyle 9+k\pi \le {\pi\over2}$. The first inequality, when solved for $k$, yields $\displaystyle k \ge -{1\over2}\cdot{\frac {18+\pi }{\pi }}=-3.3647\ldots$. The second inequality, when solved for $k$, yields $\displaystyle k\le {1\over2}\cdot{\frac {\pi -18}{\pi }}=-2.3647\ldots$. Since $k$ must be an integer, $k=-3$, and so $\tan^{-1}(\tan 9)=9+(-3)\pi=9-3\pi$.